# How to change the shape of this pocketwatch chain (along a bezier path)?

Tags: bezier-curves

I am trying to modify the following blender project of a pocketwatch:

[image]

[image]

[image]

https://easyupload.io/3fvmfs

I would like to change the shape of the chain pathway. I can see the creator included a bezier path for it, implying it was generated to follow along the path. Looking at the detail of the chain, it does not look like they manually lined up all those links like that.

It would be virtually impossible to manipulate the shape of the chain in any meaningful way if I must manipulate every link individually.

How would this chain have been generated along the bezier curve? How do I generate a new chain (or change the current one) to match it if I change that bezier curve?

Thanks.

Comment: If it is already applied with modifiers than there is no way to change it with bezier(you CAN, but it will deform too much) I would recommend to take 2 pieces, delete the rest and follow one of many tutorials on youtube like this for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_r6O_ePQYX0 (just type "chain along path blender" and you can find many tutorials about it better than me writing about it

Answer (score 1):

You should have created a straight chain, what you've got here is an already twisted chain, if you give it a *Curve* modifier with the curve as *Object*, as MikoCG says, it will get even more deformed: the curve takes the object as it exists and twist it. If the object is already twisted it will be even more.